# How to implement this design in swift 4 all the data are scrollable horizontally and vertically

Tags: swift4

I have to imbed this in my tableView . data is scrolling horizontally and vertically .[image]

Comment: Please help me its argent

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use UICollectionView for horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Comment: @NiluSahani no bro try on collectionview it’s only useful for you

Comment: please implement for me ,I shall be highly obligated

Comment: please help me

Comment: please reply me

Comment: You can try this. I will help you to complete this

Comment: my data already show in tableview and my tableview using three prototype cell  this design imbed in first prototypecell